# Python pandas csv multirow values into arrays

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv that has values spread over multiple rows like this (real data has about 70 columns)

```
id | name | alias
 1 |  Amy | Potato
   |      | Fortress
 2 | Bill | Gyroscope
...
```

Now I want to import this into a dataframe. The tricky part is reading aliases into an array if there is a multiple of them. From the example above we should get `Amy [Potato, Fortress]` and `Bill [Gyroscope]`

I can do it with row-by-row processing but I was wandering if there is some smarter built-in way.

UPD: clarified the requirement

Comment: I don't think you can do it row-by-row. Have you heard of `read_csv` of pandas?

Comment: Can you copy/paste a sample of your csv in a raw format please?

Comment: Neither, yes I have heard of read_csv but it will not construct the arrays for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv file looks like:

```
id,name,alias
1,Amy,Potato
,,Fortress
2,Bill,Gyroscope
```

You can use `ffill`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str).ffill()
print(df)

# Output
  id  name      alias
0  1   Amy     Potato
1  1   Amy   Fortress
2  2  Bill  Gyroscope
```

**Update**

> Thanks for the response! I am looking for something that will combine row 1 into the row 0 rather than create a new row. So that we get Amy [Potato, Fortress]

Use `agg`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str).ffill() \
       .groupby('id', as_index=False) \
       .agg({'id': 'first', 'name': 'first', 'alias': lambda x: list(x)})
print(df)

# Output
  id  name               alias
0  1   Amy  [Potato, Fortress]
1  2  Bill         [Gyroscope]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am looking for something that will combine row 1 into the row 0 rather than create a new row. So that we get `Amy [Potato, Fortress]`

Comment: Is your csv look like mine?

Comment: yes, pretty much. There are more multi-line columns but basically it is the same

Comment: @Rince. I updated my answer according your comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is look like below, as you describe:

```
id | name | alias
 1 |  Amy | Potato
   |      | Fortress
 2 | Bill | Gyroscope
```

Supoose this data saved in **data.txt** file, then you can simply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def str_to_nan(x):
    return [np.nan if str(i).strip() == '' else i for i in x]


df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='|').apply(lambda x: str_to_nan(x))
df = df.ffill()
```

```
Output:
    id  name    alias
0   1   Amy     Potato
1   1   Amy     Fortress
2   2   Bill    Gyroscope
```

Comment: I was not completely clear in my requirements, edited

Comment: I have updated my answer have a look also